# How to deal with empty array keys in a foreach that is inside a while loop?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

I have the following array which is being generated from a msqli query.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 21
    [1] => AAAAA
    [2] => BBBBB
    [3] => 1234567
    [4] => aaa
    [5] => bbb
    [6] => ccc
    [7] => ddd
    [8] => 2015-01-19 03:31:33
    [9] => 1
    [10] => 5
    [11] => 5, - not set -;9, - not set -;10, - not set -;11, - not set -;14, - not set -;19, 12;20, mm_cb_on;21, - not set -;27, Noe;28, Pena;62, mm_cb_off
)

Array
(
    [0] => 22
    [1] => AAAAA
    [2] => BBBBB
    [3] => 1234567
    [4] => aaa
    [5] => bbb
    [6] => ccc
    [7] => ddd
    [8] => 2015-01-19 03:31:33
    [9] => 1
    [10] => 6
    [11] => 5, - not set -;9, - not set -;10, - not set -;11, - not set -;14, - not set -;20, mm_cb_on;21, - not set -;
)

Array
(
    [0] => 23
    [1] => AAAAA
    [2] => BBBBB
    [3] => 1234567
    [4] => aaa
    [5] => bbb
    [6] => ccc
    [7] => ddd
    [8] => 2015-01-19 03:31:33
    [9] => 1
    [10] => 7
    [11] => 5, - not set -;11, - not set -;14, - not set -;19, 23;20, mm_cb_on;21, - not set -;27, Noe;28, Pena;62, mm_cb_off
)
```

I am looping through this data like so:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
    echo "<td nowrap>" .$row{'first_name'}. "</td>
          <td nowrap>" .$row{'last_name'}. "</td>
          .......";
}
```

When I get to the last key in the array, I am looping through that data, and exploding like this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
    echo "<td nowrap>" .$row{'first_name'}. "</td>
          <td nowrap>" .$row{'last_name'}. "</td>
          .......";
    $custom_fields = $row[11];
    $fields = explode(";", $custom_fields);
    foreach ($fields as $keys) {
        $key = explode(',', $keys);

        var_dump($key);
    }
}
```

That var dump produces the following array structure (for the first key in the previous array):

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] =>  - not set -
)
Array
(
    [0] => 9
    [1] =>  - not set -
)
Array
(
    [0] => 10
    [1] =>  - not set -
)
Array
(
    [0] => 11
    [1] =>  - not set -
)
Array
(
    [0] => 14
    [1] =>  - not set -
)
Array
(
    [0] => 19
    [1] =>  12
)
Array
(
    [0] => 20
    [1] =>  mm_cb_on
)
Array
(
    [0] => 21
    [1] =>  - not set -
)
Array
(
    [0] => 27
    [1] =>  Noe
)
Array
(
    [0] => 28
    [1] =>  Pena
)
Array
(
    [0] => 62
    [1] =>  mm_cb_off
)
```

I am trying to create conditionals like so:

```
if (isset($key[0]) && $key[0] == 19) { // this produce none for every row
    $prov_id = $key[1];
} else {
    $prov_id = 'None';
}

if ($key[0] == 27) {
    $fm2_fname = $key[1];
} else {
    $fm2_fname  = '';
}

if ($key[0] == 28) {
    $fm2_lname = $key[1];
} else {
    $fm2_lname  = '';
}
```

The problem I am having is in the loop some of the items do not have `$key[0] == "19"` ... How would I handle this inside the foreach loop? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What with the items do not have `$key[0] == "19"` ?

Comment: if $key[0] doesn't exist, then your explode failed. so... `isset($key[0])`?

Comment: Thanks @Marc B. I understand that, but $key[0] will always exist somewhere in the array it just wont alway equal 19 ... So `isset` will alway be true.

Comment: then what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I need to grab the value of `$key[1]` where `$key[0] == 19` and if there is not a `$key[0]` that equals 19, I need to provide an empty value.

Comment: Just put the if statements inside your loop and it will work

Comment: `isset($key[0]) && $key[0] == 19`

Comment: @Eugen I tried that too, but it produces "none" for all ??? Am i missing something in the loop?

Comment: because you are assigning values to variables not arrays `$prov_id` , `$fm2_fname` , `$fm2_lname` if you are not using the variables inside foreach

Comment: @phplover not sure I understand. I want the variable to be set as the array value

Comment: Yes, but where are you using those variables? inside the loop or outside?

Comment: @phplover inside the while loop but outside the foreach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (isset($key[0]) && $key[0] == 19) { // this produce none for every row
    $prov_id = $key[1];
} else {
    $prov_id = 'None';
}

if ($key[0] == 27) {
    $fm2_fname = $key[1];
} else {
    $fm2_fname  = '';
}

if ($key[0] == 28) {
    $fm2_lname = $key[1];
} else {
    $fm2_lname  = '';
}
```

Because you have an else on each statement, that value will be set as it is looping, so in your situation it is setting the variable to `'None'` after setting it to `$key[1]`.

Instead get rid of the `} else {`
And change variables to the following so each row has its own values:

```
$row['prov_id']
$row['fm2_fname']
$row['fm2_lname']
```

So the final code now will be like this:

```
if ($key[0] == 19)
    $row['prov_id'] = $key[1];

if ($key[0] == 27) 
    $row['fm2_fname'] = $key[1];

if ($key[0] == 28) 
    $row['fm2_lname'] = $key[1];
```

Outside the foreach loop do this for each variable

```
if (!isset($row['prov_id'])) $row['prov_id'] = '';
```